# Jquery click events stacking

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, closest

I have 3 elements. Each has an element within them that when clicked find their parent and send it away to be worked on. The problem is the click events seem to be stacking. For example if I click on Element #1, it sends away Element #1 to be worked on. Then if I click Element #3, it sends away Element #1, and Element #3. Then if  I click Element #2, it sends Element #1, Element #3, and Element #2. How do I get it to only send the one direct parent of the click event.

Relevant code:

```
    $('.tiles ').on('click', '.fa-pencil', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();

        var tile = $(this).closest(".live-tile");
        showEditDialog(tile);

    });
```

.tiles being the wrapper class all the parents share, .live-tile being the individual parents that get sent away, .fa-pencil being the child that gets clicked, and showEditDialog being the sending away.

EDIT----

```
<div class="tiles">
    <!-- <div class="live-tile" >
         <span id = "bar" class = "tile-title optionsBar"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-pencil"></i><i  class="fa fa-2x fa-times-circle"></i></span>
         <div class ="mainDiv"></div>
        <span class = "tile-title imageBar"><img class = "image" src = "http://9gag.com/favicon.ico"></img></span>
        </div>-->
</div>
```

The content within the comments (everything except .tiles) is dynamically added, but that is what it would look like.

Comment: Could you please share your markup?

Comment: Added markup in edit

Comment: Do you have multiple divs with the class tiles?

Comment: nope just the one .tiles, but it contains multiple .live-tiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I found out it was not that particular point in code cauding the issue. The showEditDialog() function was calling itself twice, and for some reason bubbling to the parent tile for the second one. I just remove the call to itself and it only called the correct one after.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Would you please accept your own answer so that others (like myself) don't think it still needs solving? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of stopPropagation. Try switching it out with `stopImmediatePropagation()`

From http://devdocs.io/jquery/event.stoppropagation

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

From http://devdocs.io/jquery/event.stopimmediatepropagation

> In addition to keeping any additional handlers on an element from
>   being executed, this method also stops the bubbling by implicitly
>   calling event.stopPropagation(). To simply prevent the event from
>   bubbling to ancestor elements but allow other event handlers to
>   execute on the same element, we can use event.stopPropagation()
>   instead.

I believe that because other handler are being executed it is causing your problem. By changing it will prevent execution as well as bubbling.

Comment: Sadly had no change, I too thought/think the event handlers are still attached to the origninally clicked elements but nothing seems to stop it.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are identifying all the buttons with the class .tiles you must parse a UNIQUE child selector into the function each time.

Comment: I didnt downvote this, but I think youre mistaken, .tiles doesnt identidy the buttons .fa-pencil does. I added markup to maybe clarify. And on click $(this) should identify the specific one, correct?

Comment: Makes more sense with the markup, but even so it has to do with the way javascript creates new variables. And no $(this) refers to the object in question to which the callback function applies which would be the window object in this case.